# HTML layout without using absolute positioning

Tags: css, html

After days of hard work (i know it would've taken a pro only a few minutes), I have finally designed the exact layout I want. The only problem now is that it uses a lot of absolute positioning, which I hear is evil or at least undesirable. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j8uvy/) of how I have done this. Can someone guide on which of these `<div>`s can avoid absolute positioning and instead use more fluid constructs?

Comment: What is the problem with absolute positioning? Does it work well for you task or not?

Comment: I don't know yet. It appears fine in FF and Chrome on my machine, but as I said, I'm new to web world and my view is based on reading people's voices from the Internet (about absolute positioning being evil).

Comment: ur rite absolute cant use for all. only for specific needs.. ur template having problems with footer content overlay..

Comment: The layout you designed can only be achieved using position: absolute. if not then you need to develop code using javascript which is not recommended. BTW, there is also css3 property [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) which does the same and also doesn't let the element out of the layout.

Comment: Absolute positioning is not evil. It is one of the oldest and best supported ways of performing layouts. It also tends to render faster than other methods in my casual tests (which makes sense; it is less for the browser to calculate). Now that's not to say you should use it all of the time, or even a majority of the time, but if you have a layout that works, meets the business need, supports the devices you want, etc. then its a fair tool for the job. You'll find a mix of layout techniques on the biggest sites in the world.

Comment: Paul irish recommend [translate](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/). Never tried it though...

Comment: it will hardly be responsive (unless use js) using absolute positions. If this is a sort of web app layout I will suggest having a look at bootstrap. it gives you layout designs and div fluid position

Comment: What browser support do you need? If you don't need a low IE support, you can go with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you can avoid using `absolute` positioning in that fiddle, becuase i didn't go through your css. but if older browser support in not a problem, you can create this layout without using `absolute` positioning at all..

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9CrUn/)

- It uses css3 `calc()` function so will only work in modern browsers.
- There's a loss of `1%` width due to the whitespace problem of `display:inline-block` elements

This is another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9CrUn/3/) using `display:flex` property which avoids the whitespace problem.
Tested and working fine on `Chrome 33.0` `FF 28` & `IE11` (This one was a surprise! :)

CSS `Flexible boxes` makes it easier to create layouts.
[Read more about Flexible Boxes @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

[Flexbox guide @ css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really good answer I'd say. Flex will become a powerful tool once it is widely supported. Your answer also lead me to css grid layout (which is still in experimental stages as of this writing). Once that bomb is in our hands, HTML will be as good at layouts as WPF containers (see it to believe it).

Answer (score -1):

Float left for the columns and use default relative positioning.  Percentage widths and set heights to px if need be.  That would the most consistent layout.

Comment: Not possible until you use css3 calc property as I commented above.